# How to check before insert?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have a table with 6 columns.

```
1.ID (number)(PK)
2.USER_ID (number)
3.ROLE_ID (number)
4.CREATED_TS (date)
5.CREATED_BY (VARCHAR2)
6.ACTIVE_IND (VARCHAR2)
```

I am inserting data via a POST REST API Call in that table. I am firing a query in Java Repository.

```
public UserRoles save(final UserRoles u) {
        final String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO VEB_USER_ROLES(ID, USER_ID, ROLE_ID, CREATED_TS, CREATED_BY, ACTIVE_IND) " +
                "VALUES(VEB_USER_ROLES_SEQ.NEXTVAL, ?, ?, ?, 'PROD_MASTER', 'Y')";
        GeneratedKeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
        jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
            @Override
            public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(insertQuery, new String[]{"ID"});
                ps.setLong(1, u.getUserId());
                ps.setLong(2, u.getRoleId());
                ps.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));   
                return ps;
            }
        }, keyHolder);
        return u;

    }
```

The query is working fine and the data is been inserted.I just want to add a check if same UserID and RoleID exists it should not insert.
for eg in the DB I have Userid '1' and roleId '1' and I send the same values ie userid '1' and role id '1' it should not get inserted.
Can anyone guide me regarding this.

Comment: Create a unique index on the two columns and handle the exception during insert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `UNIQUE` constraint on the two columns: `USER_ID` and `ROLE_ID`

```
ALTER TABLE yourtablename ADD CONSTRAINT uq_yourtablename UNIQUE(column1, column2);
```

Examples: Status on Insertion-

-- succeeds:

```
INSERT yourtablename(USER_ID, ROLE_ID) VALUES(1, 22);
```

-- succeeds:

```
INSERT yourtablename(USER_ID, ROLE_ID) VALUES(2, 23);
```

-- fails:

```
INSERT yourtablename(USER_ID, ROLE_ID) VALUES(1, 23);
```

If its not possible to `ALTER` the DB structure, you can check this also by your code:
- Before inserting new record check `USER_ID` & `ROLE_ID` exists in DB.
Use a select query & check whether a similar record exists.

Its just a idea, please make it working for you, if required:

`$exists = SELECT COUNT(*) no_of_similar_records FROM yourTableName WHERE USER_ID = $USER_ID AND ROLE_ID = $ROLE_ID`

If it has a value the do not `INSERT` again.
So here we do not need a DB update on structure.

This may help you..

Comment: A constraint is the proper way to do this. Relying on application logic will **inevitably** result in data corruption. For instance, all the SQL solutions posted here will fail in a multi-user environment if two sessions attempt to create a record for the same `(user_id, role_id)` permutation.

Comment: Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways to handle this

1. Add unique constraint on the table on columns Userid, Roleid or,
2. Do a SELECT before trying to insert to check if they already exists or,
3. Use [merge into](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/merge-enhancements-10g) insert when NOT MATCHED